# Error when using a pretrained MobileNet after loading datas (dimension error) with Python3.x Tensorflow2

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

My dataset is a folder of training data and a folder of validation data.
In each folder (train and valid) there are .npy files. Each file is (s,256,256,3) (s frames in the volume, 3 channels, and 256 the same height and width). And there is a CSV file with a label for each file.

Here is my code to load data :

```
train_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 
                             "train.csv"), names=['case', 'abnormal'], 
                             dtype = {'case' : str, 'abnormal' : np.int64})
train_image = []
for i in tqdm(range(train_df.shape[0])):
    vol = np.load(os.path.join(WORK_DIR, train_folder, train_df[img_col][i]))
    train_image.append(vol)

X_train = np.array(train_image)
y_train= np.array(train_df.drop([img_col],axis=1)) 
train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_dataset = (train_loader.shuffle(X_train.shape[0]))
```

**First question: Is it alright ?**

The idea is to use transfer learning to classify data (is it normal or abnormal ?) I'm using Tensorflow 2.4. So I decided to use a pretrained model, to extract features, then add a 2D global average pooling layer, dropout, and then dense layer. Here is my code :

```
preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_tensor=tf.keras.Input(batch_input_shape=(32,256,256, 3)),
                                               weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False

global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
max_pool_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D()
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

inputs = tf.keras.Input((256,256,3), batch_size=32)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    epochs=initial_epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_dataset, batch_size=32)
```

Where is my mistake?

Here is my issue :

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), 
found shape=(None, 32, 256, 256, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the idea of transfer learning is viable in cases where you want to use pre-trained models (which have been trained on large datasets such as imagenet). However, it should be noted that it is specific to your task. It wouldnt be a good idea to use a pre-trained model (using imagenet weights) to classify medical images (x-rays, tomography, etc) since it is really specific classification task. However, you can start adding a classification layer with n_outputs (depending on the number of classes) and only train that additional layers.

If you want to make the model more specific to your task (your dataset), you can use fine-tunning, which is also transfer learning, but you are also training some layers of your base model (see that you are setting the base_model.trainable = False and only updating weights of the classification layer). However, in this case you will also set trainable = True to a portion of the base_model layers (usually the last ones), since the first layers of a CNN model usually learn generic features of images and it is pretty sure that the weights learned by the base_model are appliable to your images.

You would also want to first train your classification layer (just as you have it). And then unfreeze a portion of the last layers of the base_model and re-trained. Check this guide from tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#train_the_model), where you can find examples of this.

Try with this:

I assume that X_train is in the form of: `[[0.2,0.3,0.001,0.3,..],[0.02,0.4,...],[...]..]` and y_train is in the form of: `[[0],[1]..[]]` right? And also normalized according to the preprocess_input function.

Lets part from having this two numpy arrays, which is your training data.

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=(256,256,3),
                                               weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False

global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
max_pool_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D() # I dont see where this is used
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

x = base_model.output
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
classification_layer = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=classification_layer)

base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# I added ImageDataGenerator instead
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split = 0.2).flow(X_train, 
                                                                  y_train, 
                                                                  batch_size = 32, 
                                                                  subset = 'training')
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2).flow(X_train, 
                                                              y_train, 
                                                              batch_size = 32, 
                                                              subset = 'validation')

history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs = initial_epochs, validation_data= val_generator)
```

Comment: Hi @Francisco thank you for your explaination, I understand what you said. Then, I checked the link you said from tensorflow and I add base_model.trainable=True and unfreeze some layers to retrain the first layers. However,  I still can't understand my issue. There is the same error, it seems that a None dimension is added, but I don't know why..

Comment: try setting input_shape=(256,256,3) instead of using input_tensor.

Comment: Hi @Francisco I tried to use code you provided. Before I checked I had the right X_train form, It seems that it works ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Leili_Kue that is great to hear! No problems! If all your questions have been solved and my answer in correct, please mark it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `batch_input_shape` in line:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_tensor=tf.keras.Input(batch_input_shape=(32,256,256, 3)),
                                                   weights='imagenet')
```

by doing this:

```
base_model._layers[0].batch_input_shape = (None, 256, 256, 3)
```

For more information: check this [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/issues/152)

Comment: Thanks @zaw ish for your answer. 
But I still have the same Error :(

Comment: Hi Leili, I've edited the answer, and attached a link as well. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey zaw, thanks for your update, I checked it and I made corrections, but it still doesn't work... I changed my model with a VGG16 but it's the same issue. It seems there is a problem with the imput data size. In my dataloader data shape is (32,256,256,3) but he doesn't take 32 as batch size but as another dimension. I don't know if it's clear... Do you have any idea ? I lost in my mind, I don't know wat to do...

Comment: Please upload it on colab, and share me the link so I can debug it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips that may come helpful to you. When you build your data set, in the case of image data, you should check by plotting some of the samples from it. For example:

```
 train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
 for i, (x,y) in train_loader:
     if i == 1: break
     print(x.shape, y.shape)
     plt.imshow(x[i])
     plt.title(y[i])
```

And when building your model, it's actually a good practice to plot the model to see whether it's built properly or not. And if possible pass some dummy samples to ensure everything is ok.

```
# define layer 
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, 
                                               input_shape=(256,256,3),
                                               weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False
global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

# adding up 
inputs = tf.keras.Input((256,256,3), batch_size=32)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)

# build all 
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Now, you can pass some dummy samples and plot your model.

```
model(tf.ones((1, 256, 256, 3))) # pass one dummy samples 
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model) # to plot
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Innat I'll try it, It will be really usefull to check everything. I'll tell you if it goes right or not

Comment: Great. Let me know if it works for you or feel free to ask any questions.